# c# compare combobox SelectedItem with enum value

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I like to know if its possible to compare the selectedItem inside a combobox with a enum value. For example

```
if (cmb.SelectedItem == Enum.Value) ...
```

At the moment I am doing by ToString()

```
if (cmb.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Value")
```

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you just try it?

Answer (score 5):

Cast `SelectedItem`  to your enum

```
if((MyEnum)cmb.SelectedItem == MyEnum.Value) ...
```

Comment: Of course, probably learnt this years ago and of course has escaped my mind. thanks